# Treadmill workouts for weight loss

Tags: weight-loss, workout-types

I recently spent some time googling to find treadmill workouts for specifically weight loss, but it turned out to get nothing than couple of mediocre essays. Can anyone recommend either online resources or provide sample workouts for treadmills?

Comment: How much do you weigh, what's your running experience and current condition?

Answer (score 5):

High Intensity Interval Training (HIIT) would be a good type of exercise to do. Workouts are usually short and aimed at burning fat. An example would be running for a minute followed by sprinting for 30 seconds followed by running for a minute etc. Another example is running at an incline for a couple minutes followed by level running. If your treadmill can simulate a natural running course with hills and valleys that would have a similar effect.

Here are a couple websites that explain the details:

- [Treadmill Workouts Using High Intensity Intervals - HIIT](http://walking.about.com/od/treadmillworkouts/a/treadmillhiit.htm)
- [How I Do HIIT on a Treadmill](http://www.tryingfitness.com/how-i-do-hiit-on-a-treadmill/)
- [High Intensity Interval Training](http://www.askmen.com/sports/bodybuilding_100/135b_fitness_tip.html)

Comment: Personally I wouldn't recommend overweight people to start sprinting, besides they don't even have to because due to their weight, their workouts are already a lot heavier at lower speeds...

Comment: That's true, but not everybody that wants to lose weight is obese. "Overweight" doesn't always describe people that want to lose weight either. Perhaps I should preface all answers with "Consult a doctor before beginning a new workout routine".

Answer (score 2):

If your focused on losing weight and losing body fat, you should concentrate on building muscle mass just as much as doing high intensity cardio.

Here is my exercise program that has helped me lose 10 lbs.  Just a note:  I am 5'11" and currently weight 185lbs.

Everyday I do the below scheduled workout, then post workout I do:

- 40 Minutes of elliptical
- 15 Minutes of treadmill at 3.5 incline

If you do not have the elliptical, it is suggested to do 40 minutes of cardio post-workout, so I would do something like:

- 10 minutes treadmill warmup at 3.5 speed w/ 1.5 incline
- 25 minutes treadmill at 4.5 speed w/ 3.5 inline
- 5 minutes treadmill cool-down at 3.0 speed w/ 1.5 incline

---

### M, W, F

Chest:
Bench press 5 x 6-10
Flat bench flyes 5 x 6-10
Incline bench press 6 x 6-10
Cable crossovers 6 x 10-12
Dips (body weight) 5 x failure
Dumbell pullovers 5 x 10-12.

Back:
Wide-grip chins (to front) 6 x failure
T-bar rows 5 x 6-10
Seated pulley rows 6 x 6-10
One-arm dumbell rows 5 x 6-10
Straight-leg deadlifts 6 x 15

Legs:
Squats 6 x 8-12
Leg press 6 x 8-12
Leg extensions 6 x 12-15
Leg curls 6 x 10-12
Barbell lunges 5 x 15

Calves:
Standing calf raises 10 x 10
Seated calf raises 8 x 15
Oneplegged calf raises (holding dumbells) 6x12

Forearms:
Wrist curls (forearms on knees) - 4 sets, 10 reps
Reverse barbell curls - 4 sets, 8 reps
Wright roller machine - to failure

Abs: 
½ hour of a variety of nonspecific abdominal exercises, done virtually nonstop.

---

### T, Th, Sat

Biceps: 
Barbell curls 6 x 6-10
Seated dumbell curls 6 x 6-10
Dumbell concentration curls 6 x 6-10

Triceps:
Close-grip bench presses 6 x 6-10
Pushdowns 6 x 6-10
French press (barbell) 6 x 6-10
One-arm triceps extensions (dumbell) 6 x 6-10

Shoulders:
Seated barbell presses 6 x 6-10
Lateral raises (standing) 6 x 6-10
Rear-delt lateral raises 5 x 6-10
Cable lateral raises 5 x 10-12

Calves , Forearms & Abs: 
Same as Monday, Wednesday, Friday workout

---

The above is the Arnold muscle workout schedule located [here](http://www.trulyhuge.com/news/tips63jb.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Well instead of wasting time in searching for treadmill workouts for weight loss. You should ask yourself whether its important to stay for more time on treadmill or to try some harsh intensity workouts and after few days get fedup of practicing them daily (As those workouts are very hard to follow).

Being a fitness consultant with more than a decade of experience in personal health and physical fitness, i will recommend you to look for entertaining treadmill workouts that will make you stay on your treadmill for long time, indirectly helping you in burning more calories.

I found one [useful article](https://www.treadmillreviewguru.com/articles/treadmill-workouts/) where they have mentioned some great treadmill workouts that are not very hard to follow and will keep you entertained on treadmill for a long period of time, resulting in burning of more calories.

Answer (score -5):

If you ask us the simplest way to lose the body fat or fat with the help of a treadmill, then I simply suggest you take care of your diet and remove sugar and extra carbs from your diet and then try to do HIIT or High Intensity Running or Jogging workouts with the help of treadmill, do this for four or five days a week for three weeks.

If you do this without any problem, you'll definitely see some changes in your body.

Comment: If you are going to link to your own site, you can do so on a limited basis. However, you must disclose that affiliation in any answer. See [these guidelines](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Also, whatever you link should be relevant to the question, not just a review of a random treadmill (Which I have removed from your post).